# How to make a Woocommerce Grouped Product not purchasable 24 hours before set date based on ACF date field?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I think I have a pretty specific question. I have only grouped products in my WooCommerce Shop. With ACF, I added a new meta field "date". For context, my main products are actually events and the linked products under it, are food options people can pre-order for the event. However, people should only be able to pre-order food up to 24 hours before the event takes place. That's why I added the date field with ACF.

I know there is the "is_purchasable" condition but I am completely new to WooCommerce and don't even know where to start to write the function that based on the ACF date value the product should not be purchasable anymore 24 hours before the event.

Can someone help me with that or point me to a resource where I can find similar codes that I can adjust for my need?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, here is the code that works for me:

```
function unpublish_24h_before() {
// Get all products
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$products = get_posts( $args );

// Check expiration date for each product
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    $expiration_date = get_field( 'date', $product->ID );
    if ( !empty( $expiration_date ) ) {
        $expiration_date = strtotime( $expiration_date );
        $time_left = $expiration_date - time();
        if ( $time_left <= 24 * 60 * 60 ) {
            // Move the product to the trash
            $product->post_status = 'draft';
        wp_update_post( $product );
        }
    }
}} unpublish_24h_before();
```